# Trying to remove new lines and spaces using regex

Tags: php, regex

I am attempting to remove some line breaks and spaces from a multiline string I have, such as the following:

```
    Toronto (YTZ)
    to
    Montreal (YUL)
```

I tried doing:

```
$matched = preg_replace('/[\n]/', '', $string);
var_dump($matched);
```

but all it returns is:

```
    Montreal (YUL)
```

I've tried all sorts of combinations of regular expressions, but it only ever seems to find what I specify, replace it, and display anything AFTER the matched expression.

I'm sure it's something simple, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try `\r\n` if you are using Windows instead of `\n`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\n only represents "go to line" if it is between double quotes in PHP "\n"... Your regex should be `"/[\n]/"` not `'/[\n]/'`

Anyway, don't use a regular expression for that, but `str_replace("\n",'',$string)` instead. It's faster.

Answer (score 0):

As Kash already noticed you, expression of new line in different OS can be different.
That's where PHP_EOL constant is used. This constant is defined depending on OS.

```
$string = str_replace(PHP_EOL, '', $string);
```

if string could be created on different machine, then it would be better to replace "\r" and "\n" separately

```
$string = str_replace(array("\r", "\n"), '', $string);
```

Comment: That's a good idea. 
Except if you're reading a file that was created on a different OS.
In any case, you've to be careful I agreee with you.

Comment: $string = str_replace(array("\r", "\n"), '', $string); :D no prob?

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = preg_replace('/\n+(?=.)/', " ",
       preg_replace('/^\s*/m', "",
       $str));
```

Check this code [here](http://ideone.com/BbVJE).